# Web Speech API crashes suddenly and stop

Tags: jquery, html

Im working with Web Speech API in Chrome 79.x.x in my localhost.

I works ok...but suddenly it crashes and stop suddenly..how to stop this behaviour?

Im just using a basic script

```js
$(".toread").on("click", function() {

  var toRead = $(this).attr("toread");;

  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(toRead);
  msg.lang = 'de-DE';
  msg.rate = 0.6;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toread" toread="foo bar">click</div>
```

After the speech system stops, I need to restart my laptop to make it work again...otherwise it continues in silence...

Comment: Seems to work fine here on W10, wonder if OS could make a difference?

Comment: Im in Windows 8.1 but I dont think it could be the OS

Comment: Does the above snippet on Stack Overflow work for you, or does it exhibit the same problem?

Comment: I can hear "foo bar" now. I had to restar my computer to do so.

Comment: I'm developing a complex application using Web Speech API and have observed this issue as well. I develop and test on Windows 8.1 machine and we run the product on another Windows machine (not sure the version). Both manifest the same issues. Note that in our case we never need to reboot the OS, just the Chrome browser.

Comment: I suspect (tests needed) one of two possible issues: a) when you do speech recognition in incremental mode, if you keep going on and on, it could cause problems (ie: buffer overflow or something). or b) I've observed issues after several days of constant usage (never on a fresh boot). So could be something over time. I will be investigating deeper. Will update here if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The window.speechSynthesis object can be left in an undetermined state and it will not restart unless any pending utterances are cleared out.

You may find it helpful to call window.speechSynthesis.cancel() at the start (in an init routine). I added the call to cancel at the top of my init function and the speech would work after reloading the page (instead of quitting and restarting Chrome).

Watch the speechSynthesis.pending, speechSynthesis.speaking, and speechSynthesis.paused properties and see if you can find a pattern when it has stopped speaking. That should guide you in debugging to prevent leaving the speechSynthesis object in that state.